# Do DeleteFile() Or CopyFile() throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, file

I use the `DeleteFile` and `CopyFile` methods. Do these functions throw exceptions or just set `errno` and `lastError`?  Do I need to surround this code with `try` and `catch`?

Comment: These functions are not part of standard C++. We need to know where they're defined before we can say how they behave.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951586/the-copy-task-failed-unexpectedly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're referring to the Win32 API functions, the answer is no.  No Win32 functions throw, because it is a C API.

Answer (score 5):

As @jeffamaphone says, they don't throw exceptions because they are C functions.

For errors, they return 0 and set an error code that you can retrieve via `GetLastError()`.  Neither sets `errno`, because they're Windows APIs.